# Can't read messages from by kafka consumer in Spring cloud stream

Tags: spring, stream, cloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVBHS.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPd4T.png)# I can read kafka messages with kafka consumer console but when I tried with consumer function I got the console

This is my function code :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Service
public class PageEventService {

    @Bean
    public Consumer<PageEvent> input()
    {
        return  (input)->{
            System.out.println("******************");
            System.out.println(input.toString());
            System.out.println("******************");
        };
    }

}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: R1
```

I tried to read messages sent by a producer but I couldn't and I got this console

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you're on the right track. Try adjusting your configuration. Change `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input` to `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0`.

Why "in," and wherefore "0?" The "in" specifies the flow of data into your function, i.e., a producer would have an `-out-` binding, a processor would have both an `-in-` and `-out-`, and a consumer just has an `-in-`. The "0" is an index provides support functions with multiple inputs and outputs, which you are not doing. Since you have one input, you only need `-in-0`.

Here's an example configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: yourConsumer
      bindings:
        yourConsumer-in-0:
          destination: yourTopic
```

To go a bit deeper, here are some resources:

- To better understand the literal `-in`'s and `out`'s, see the section of the spring cloud function doc on function arity: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_arity. You may find that studying spring cloud function helps with understanding the naming conventions better.
- Tanzu Developer center has a deep example of using SCS with multiple Kafka topics: https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-p3/
- SCS reference docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/
- SCS sample projects: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples